# Remove Default/Standard fields from activities

Tags: activities

is it possible to remove some of the default/standard fields for activities?

For example, when creating a new activity type it includes "location" as a standard field. However, you can't search or report by this field. I'm not sure what it's purpose is, and I would rather create a custom field that can be searched.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not switch this off as a user I am afraid. But you can hide it with a little jQuery to the template if you know how to do this. Is this something you can do?

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response. No I don't know how to hide it with a jQuery - is it straight forward to do? Are there any instructions? :) thanks!

Comment: Or css might be even better to hide a field. Neither is straightforward unless you already know how to do it, in which case both are relatively straighforward. If you want a minimal path, then just hide the field in your theme using a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want the location field to be searchable, it'd be better to address that issue than to create a new field.

I'd also warn that activities have issues when scaling your site. A lot of activities get created by default, and the api tends to break with a lot of records (my experience was from 4.4, and the api implementation of the limit records was only throwing out the extra ones after loading them all).

Comment: the api tends to break with a lot of records?