# Contact SubType check fail in Smarty TPL file

Tags: contacts, smarty

Have  strange issue checking contact type in **\templates\CRM\Contact\Form\Contact.tpl**

This code prints  **Organization / Society**

```
{$contactType} / {$contactSubType}
```

This code prints **Organization / Society**

```
{if $contactType eq 'Organization'}
   {$contactType} / {$contactSubType}
{/if}
```

But this one prints nothing

```
{if $contactSubType eq 'Society'}
       {$contactType} / {$contactSubType}
{/if}
```

And this one prints nothing

```
{if $contactType eq 'Organization' && $contactSubType eq 'Society'}
       {$contactType} / {$contactSubType}
{/if}
```

Shouldn't it "just" work? Or it's another bit of CiciCRM magic?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It might well be that modifying a template is not the best route to whatever you are trying to do (and it hardly ever is).

Comment: In the DB contact_sub_type uses a special character to split multiple contact types. If this is being carried through to smarty then 'eq' might not produce a match (but the non-HTML character wouldn't be printed to screen). Can smarty check whether the $contactSubType just contains 'Society'?

Comment: @AndrewWest : That's probably it, thanks a million for useful cue! Hope Smarty has  kind of "eliminate special characters"  built-in. Wish I could mark your comment as an answer.

Comment: no probs! report back if that fixes it and I can add it as a proper answer.

Comment: @AndrewWest : it definitely works after eliminating of U+001 special char added at the beginning at the end of contact sub-type name, thanks again for proper answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(adding as an answer - see comment thread above)

In the DB, contact_sub_type uses a special character to split multiple contact types. If this is being carried through to smarty then 'eq' might not produce a match (but the non-HTML character wouldn't be printed to screen). Can smarty check whether the $contactSubType just contains 'Society'?

Answer (score 1):

If isset contact ID ($contactId), you can use API in smarty like this:

```
        {crmAPI var='result' entity='Contact' action='get' id=$contactId}
        {foreach from=$result.values item=contact}
            <div>$contact.contact_type</div>
            {if $contact.contact_type eq 'Organization'}
                {* ... html ....*}
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide Contact Details, the best way is explained in this post:
[How do I edit activity forms?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9349/how-do-i-edit-activity-forms/9350?noredirect=1#comment9167_9350)

In my opinion the best way is to create a little extension and add a template with some jQuery code to hide the Contact Details. But you could give the css way a go too?

Comment: Thank you for valuable input, however, it doesn't answer the initial question, which is "why contact subtype check fails in smarty template, where contact type check works". Besides, as it was stated, elements should be hidden depending on contact subtype, which returns us to a starting point again..